# Facebook Real time Updates in user feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am creating a web application using php. I have a facebook sign in link in my application. When a user sign in I would like to show his real time updates on his news feed and wall in my site. I am using facebook PHP SDK.

I have read about real time updates in facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Any Idea of implementing this using facebook real time updates.

If not possible I am planning to to it using polling facebook server at a specific interval.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “his real time updates”? Real-time updates is just a mechanism to let your app know if any relevant fields of the user profile are getting changed – but I can’t see what about that you’d want to show on your site. Or do you maybe have a wrong understanding of what real-time-updates are? They do _not_ notify you of new postings that the user made, if that’s what your hoping for.

Comment: In My case I wiant to show the users news feeds in my site. I think my understanding regarding the realtime updates was wrong. In my case I need to use polling method right?

Comment: Yeah, correct. This is not a use case for real-time updates, because they have a completely different meaning.